# Angularjs - setTimeout function in ng-init

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i can use two function on `ng-init` ? how?
i've tried an `setTimeout` to run an function to open a modal and after a time period , it call the function that closes the modal , but does not work ...

like this :

```
ng-init="setTimeout(closeModal, 2000) && openModal();"
```

both functions are inside the controller:

```
function ($scope, $stateParams, $ionicModal, $window, $timeout ) {




  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  $scope.openModal = function() {
      alert("funcionou!");
    //$scope.modal.show();
      $timeout(function(){
$scope.modal.show(); 

},0)

  };

  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
  // Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.modal.remove();
  });
  // Execute action on hide modal
  $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
  // Execute action on remove modal
  $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`.

second use `;` instead of `&&` at the end of each function when calling multiple functions

```
ng-init="$timeout(closeModal, 2000); openModal();"
```

add this to your controller

```
$scope.$timeout = $timeout;
```

inject the `$timeout` to the controller also

Comment: run only the openModal(); :/

Comment: @Mr.Malaka no prob bro

Answer (score 1):

```
ng-init="initialFunction()"
```

Inside your controller write:

```
function initialFunction(){
$timeout(closeModal, 2000); openModal();
}
```